# It is possible to use urllib.urequest on pico

Tags: raspberry-pi-pico

Does anyone have experience using "urllib.urequest" on a pico?
I cannot import the module (via tools - manage packages (Thonny))

When I try to install it, it reports a error :-(

I would like to use it to open a url with some parameters (id, ip address)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem too. I needed to manually install the file by downloading the package from [here](https://pypi.org/project/micropython-urllib.urequest/#files), extracting the files then copying the urllib folder to the lib directory on the pico.

Fortunately the file is small with no dependencies so seems to work easily enough.